# A step in Stein's proof of the Fourier inversion formula in the book Complex Analysis

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-transform

In E. M. Stein's *Complex Analysis*, Ch 4, pp. 116, proof of the Fourier inversion formula, there is the following step of derivation:

$$\int_0^\infty{\hat f(\xi)e^{2{\pi}ix\xi}d\xi}$$

$$=\int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u-ib)e^{-2\pi i(u-x-ib)\xi}dud\xi$$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u-ib)\int_0^\infty e^{-2\pi i(u-x-ib)\xi}d\xi du$$

where $\hat f(\xi)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(x)$. $f(z)$ is assumed to be holomorphic in a strip region $|\text {Im}(z)|<a$ containing the real axis, and $0<b<a$.

My question may be trivial, but I do not know how to justify that the two integration can be exchanged in order. Is there any theorem that provides sufficient conditions for this kind of double integrals to be exchangeable? Thanks.

Comment: You would need some appropriate decay assumptions on $f$. In case, for instance, $f$ is constant, its Fourier transform would be a Dirac mass, so the formulas written above only hold in a weak sense, anyway.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Yes, Stein has assumed that $|f(z)|<=A/{(1+x^2)}$ for some constant $A$, for any z in the strip region. How does this decay assumption guarantees the exchangeability?

Comment: @YourongZang: When there are only finitely many terms, the summations can be exchanged pretty obviously. What if it's an infinite summation?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: Although, I guess that isn't enough as the final integral is also only defined in a weak sense.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou: With Stein's decay assumption, the integrand here is absolutely integrable, which allows us to apply the Fubini's theorem to justify the exchange of order of integration. It seems like the gap is filled. What do you mean by "the final integral is also only defined in a weak sense"? How does that matters? Thanks.

Comment: Right... we do have exponential decay from the integrating factor, nevermind.